# AsyncLocal Value is Null after being set from within Application_BeginRequest()

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

In the following example, I am setting a value to an `AsyncLocal<string>` variable on my `HttpApplication` subclass (i.e. Global.asax) from within `Application_BeginRequest()`:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static AsyncLocal<string> AsyncLocalState = new AsyncLocal<string>();

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AsyncLocalState.Value = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;
    }

    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var path = AsyncLocalState.Value;
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var path = AsyncLocalState.Value;
    }
}
```

Later on, I will attempt to access the value of this `AsyncLocal` variable from within a handler, such as an MVC action method, or even just a plain `IHttpHandler`.

If I send a large enough request (e.g. a POST with more than 15KB of data -- the larger the request, the easier it is to observe), there is a very good chance that the value of `AsyncLocalState` is NULL when accessed from a handler *even though it was set on `BeginRequest`*.

This is reproducible from a brand-new ASP.NET project without any other libraries/modules/handlers loaded.

Is this a bug? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong? Or is ASP.NET just too unstable for this?

Addition note: the exact same behavior is observed if I instead use `CallContext.LogicalGetData`/`CallContext.LogicalSetData`.

Platform: ASP.NET, .NET 4.6.2, on Windows 7

**Update:** After trying to dig around, I've found a lot of references to, but nothing authoritatively saying that the `ExecutionContext` *does not* flow between ASP.NET pipeline events (except when it does?). And both `AsyncLocal` and the logical call context are based on the `ExecutionContext`.

Comment: Are you sure / can you check that the `BeginRequest` handler and the later method are both in fact [in the same async context](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35802014/11683)?

Comment: @GSerg I'm not exactly sure how to check that. I hooked up a `ValueChangedHandler` to the `AsyncLocal` and it doesn't get called after initially being set. It's also just weird how to depends so much on the size of the request - small requests consistently "work" and large requests do not consistently "work".

Comment: You check that by making sure `SynchronizationContext.Current` returns the same object from the event handler and from the method. `ValueChangedHandler` should not fire because the value does not change, it's just that can't be seen from different contexts like a `ThreadLocal` value cannot be seen from different threads.

Comment: It also doesn't seem very weird that small requests get through; that is often an indication of a race condition. Neither small nor big requests work reliably, but small ones are very likely to have time to get through.

Comment: @GSerg It seems that the `SynchronizationContext.Current` instance is the same even when the AsyncLocal fails to flow. I tested it by setting it to a regular static variable in `BeginRequest` and then comparing in the handler.

Comment: @GSerg regarding the request size; you're onto something about the timing. If I break inside of `BeginRequest` after setting the `AsyncLocal` value, and pause for a few moments (or even just `Thread.Sleep(2000)`), then it works more often.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The closest thing to an authoritative answer is [this comment](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/31#issuecomment-285206180) by [David Fowl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45091/davidfowl) on GitHub.

The `ExecutionContext` *does not flow* between ASP.NET pipeline events if these events do not execute synchronously. Therefore, don't use `AsyncLocal` or the logical `CallContext` to persist state; use `HttpContext.Items`.

Update: .NET 4.7.1 adds a new callback method, `HttpApplication.OnExecuteRequestStep`, which per documentation "*provides extensibility to the ASP.NET pipeline to make it easy for developers to implement features in ambient context scenarios and build libraries that care about ASP.NET execution flow (for example, tracing, profiling, diagnostics, and transactions).*"

This is precisely what someone would need in order to restore the `AsyncLocal` state or the logical `CallContext` between ASP.NET pipeline events.

Comment: Can you explain how the CallContext could be restored using the `OnExecuteRequestStep`?